# cybersource-rest-client These dependencies were not found (Vue.js)

Tags: vue.js, npm, cybersource

I am trying to create a new app in vue.js. Basically just wanting the same output from cybersource microform node.
https://github.com/CyberSource/cybersource-flex-samples-node

In my vue project main.js

import cybersourceRestApi from '../node_modules/cybersource-rest-client';

var instance = new cybersourceRestApi.KeyGenerationApi(configObj);

I am encountering an error with its dependencies. There's a lot missing but here's first 3 examples

- ApiClient in ./node_modules/cybersource-rest-client/src/index.js
- api/CaptureApi in ./node_modules/cybersource-rest-client/src/index.js
- api/ConversionDetailsApi in ./node_modules/cybersource-rest-client/src/index.js
  [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUlFq.png)